# How to get records based on an offset around a particular record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm building a search UI which searches for comments. When a user clicks on a search result (comment), I want to show the surrounding comments.

My model:

```
Group (id, title) - A Group has many comments
Comment (id, group_id, content)
```

For example:

When a user clicks on a comment with `comment.id` equal to 26. I would first find all the comments for that group:

```
comment = Comment.find(26)
comments = Comment.where(:group_id => comment.group_id)
```

I now have all of the group's comments. What I then want to do is show `comment.id` 26, with a max of 10 comments before and 10 comments after.

How can I modify comments to show that offset?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds simple, but it's tricky to get the best performance for this. In any case, you *must* let the database do the work. That will be faster by an order of magnitude than fetching all rows and filter / sort on the client side.

If by "before" and "after" you mean smaller / bigger `comment.id`, and we further assume that there can be gaps in the id space, this ***one*** query should do all:

```sql
WITH x AS (SELECT id, group_id FROM comment WHERE id = 26) -- enter value once
(
SELECT *
FROM   x
JOIN   comment c USING (group_id)
WHERE  c.id > x.id
ORDER  BY c.id
LIMIT  10
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT *
FROM   x
JOIN   comment c USING (group_id)
WHERE  c.id < x.id
ORDER  BY c.id DESC
LIMIT  10
)
```

I'll leave paraphrasing that in Ruby syntax to you, that's not my area of expertise.

Returns 10 earlier comments and 10 later ones. Fewer if fewer exist. Use `<=` in the 2nd leg of the `UNION ALL` query to include the selected comment itself.

If you need the rows sorted, add another query level on top with `ORDER BY`.

Should be very fast in combination with these two **indexes** for the table `comment`:

- one on `(id)` - probably covered automatically the primary key.
- one on `(group_id, id)`

For read-only data you could create a materialized view with a gap-less row-number that would make this even faster.

[More explanation about parenthesis, indexes, and performance in this closely related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14081944/939860)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
comment = Comment.find(26)
before_comments = Comment.
  where('created_at <= ?', comment.created_at).
  where('id != ?', comment.id).
  where(group_id: comment.group_id).
  order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
after_comments = Comment.
  where('created_at >= ?', comment.created_at).
  where('id != ?', comment.id).
  where(group_id: comment.group_id).
  order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
```

Comment: How do you make sure to only get the comments in the correct group_id ?

Comment: I was curious if this was possible w one query versus several?

Comment: You can probably write up a complex SQL query that will do all of the above in one shot, but it will suffer in readability.